# Unable to format timestamp in pyspark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I have a `CSV` data like the below:

```
time_value,annual_salary
5/01/2019 1:02:16,120.56
06/01/2019 2:02:17,12800
7/01/2019 03:02:18,123.00
08/01/2019 4:02:19,123isdhad
```

Now, I want to convert to the `timestamp` column. So, I created a view out of these records and tried to convert it but it throws an error:

```
spark.sql("select to_timestamp(time_value,'M/dd/yyyy H:mm:ss') as time_value from table")
```

**`Error`**:

```
Text '5/1/2019 1:02:16' could not be parsed
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the error that I am seeing there, this is concerning the Date Format issue.

Text `'5/1/2019 1:02:16'` could not be parsed

But your time format is specified as such

```
'M/dd/yyyy H:mm:ss'
```

You can see that the day-specific is `/1/` but your format is `dd` which expects two digits.

Please try the following format:

```
'M/d/yyyy H:mm:ss'
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried your SQL no problem. It may be a problem with the spark version. I used 2.4.8

[image: screenshot here]

Comment: The format has changed. I need in the format of `"/"` and also when you try to select a specific value post-conversion it throws an error.